# WSO2 BPS Tooling Link Could Not Be Found When Installing the BPS Tooling Plugin

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I'm currently following the WSO2 documentation on installing the BPS tooling plugin and the link given for the BPS tooling is not working(Step 4).

https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/Installing+the+BPS+Tooling+Plug-In

[image: Could not find BPS Tool]

Any resolution or an alternative method to install the same is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be referring to these documents. These are for the old BPS server, which was later merged with EI and now it's discontinued. BPMN and BPEL extensions are already there in Integration Studio, hence you don't have to install any additional plugins. You can simply create a new project with the relevant type and start building your workflows. [Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Business+Process+Tutorials+) are tutorials you can refer to.

[image]